# Objective C, using an if statement with a button's text

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, uibutton

I am trying to code an application that runs the classic "Tic Tac Toe" game for a school project. I am currently trying to write an if statement that makes it so that when the button to select "X" or "O" for a certain space is clicked again, the text does not change. My current code is this:

```
if ([topLEFT.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"X"]);
{
    [topLEFT.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:120]];

    [topLEFT setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if ([topLEFT.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"O"]);
{
    [topLEFT.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:120]];

    [topLEFT setTitle:@"O" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [topLEFT setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This is only telling me that my "If statement has empty body". How would I change this so that when the Button's text is equal to "X" or "O", that the text will just stay that way until a reset button is pressed?

Comment: remove  " ; " from if ([topLEFT.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"X"]);, you made a syntax error

Comment: fyi, You shouldn't store state in the UI like that (setting and reading out the button title as a variable) Make a model object that manages the game state independently of any UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of each `if`.